# Which bits are which in a struct with bitfields?

Tags: c, structure, bit-fields

```
#include <string.h>
#include <malloc.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <memory.h>

typedef struct AA {
    int a1:5;
    int a2:2;
} AA;

int main() {
    AA aa;
    char cc[100];
    strcpy(cc, "0123456789");
    memcpy(&aa, cc, sizeof(AA));
    printf("%d\n", aa.a1);
    printf("%d\n", aa.a2);
    return 0;
}
```

I mean I know that `sizeof(AA)` is `sizeof(int)` equals `4` byte, and after copying `"0123"` to `aa` the binary number is

```
00110011，00110010，00110001，00110000
    3         2        1         0
```

but i don't understand which bits are `a1:5` or `a2:2`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The arrangements of bitfields is not standardized.

Based on your results, `a1` holds `10000` and `a2` holds `01`. One way this could arise is if `a1` is the lowest 5 bits of `cc[0]` and `a2` is the next-lowest 2 bits .

That is, `cc[0]` is `00110000` which is being divided as `0 01 10000` .

If you did some more experimentation with values you could find out for sure which order your compiler is using.